# how can I select object from image and replace it with other one by using c++ and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nukGU.jpg)
for example if i need to select the Ipad and I need to replace it by other thing with the same size

Comment: Need more info. Do you already have the location of the iPad in the target image and you simply want to insert a new image in that location? Or do you need to find the iPad in the target image first?

Answer (score 3):

Let's say, we want to put an Android tablet from another image over the iPad.

Knowing corner coordinates of both objects on both images, you can use OpenCV `getPerspectiveTransform` function to create the transformation matrix. Make an empty mask, use `fillPoly` to draw a quadrangle on it, corresponding to the Android corner points, fill it with 1-s, it's going to be the binary mask. Apply the perspective transform, calculated earlier, to both the mask and the android image (`warpPerspective`). Copy the transformed Android image over the original iPad image with `copyTo` function, using the transformed mask. Done.

Here's a 'proof of concept' Python implementation, just because I did something not so different not so long ago. Click all the Android corners in order, then the iPad corners in the same order, press `A` key to apply the transform. Don't expect miracles from it, of course - it's not going to paint missing edges for you, etc.

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def on_mouse_click_from(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global image_from, points_from
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(image_from, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        points_from.append([x, y])
        cv2.imshow("Image1", image_from)

def on_mouse_click_to(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global image_to, points_to
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        cv2.circle(image_to, (x, y), 2, (255, 0, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        points_to.append([x, y])
        cv2.imshow("Image2", image_to)

points_from = []
points_to = []

image_from = cv2.imread("android.jpg")
image_to = cv2.imread("ipad.jpg")
max_dim = [max(x, y) for x, y in zip(image_from.shape[:2], image_to.shape[:2])][::-1]
max_dim = tuple(max_dim)
image_from = cv2.resize(image_from, max_dim)
image_to = cv2.resize(image_to, max_dim)

clone_from = image_from.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("Image1")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image1", on_mouse_click_from)

clone_to = image_to.copy()
cv2.namedWindow("Image2")
cv2.setMouseCallback("Image2", on_mouse_click_to)

image_res = None
cv2.namedWindow("Result")

while True:
    cv2.imshow("Image1", image_from)
    cv2.imshow("Image2", image_to)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("r"):
        image_from = clone_from.copy()
        image_to = clone_to.copy()
        points_from = []
        points_to = []
    elif key == ord("a"):
        trans = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(np.array(points_from, dtype='f4'), np.array(points_to, dtype='f4'))

        height, width, n_colors = clone_from.shape
        stencil = np.zeros((height, width, n_colors))
        contours = [np.array(points_from)]
        color = [1, 1, 1]
        cv2.fillPoly(stencil, contours, color)

        stencil = cv2.warpPerspective(stencil, trans, (width, height))

        img_from_transformed = cv2.warpPerspective(clone_from, trans, (width, height))

        cnd = (stencil != 0)
        image_res = clone_to.copy()
        image_res[cnd] = img_from_transformed[cnd]      

        cv2.imwrite("result.jpg", image_res)
        cv2.imshow("Result", image_res)
    elif key == ord("q"):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1) First, select the object to be replaced using [Mousecallback](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#setmousecallback) fuction from opencv. You can find a simple demo [here](https://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/09/20/roi-bounding-box-selection-of-mat-images-in-opencv/)

2) When selecting the object, save the 4 coordinates of the object being selected. Find the size of the rectangle by using these coordinates.

3) Use [Resize](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=resize#resize) function to resize the image(with which you want to replace the original)

4) Now You can simply use copyTo function to do the replacement. Check [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/58414/how-to-replace-part-of-the-image-with-another-image-roi/)

Hope this helps!